# Does the binary search for a missing element always return the element just before the place it would have been if it were present?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

This is similar to `lower_bound` in C++, and the Javadoc for binary search also mentions this: "index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)."

I've been able to verify it's true for a few examples and I'm pretty sure it's true. However, I'm not able to prove this so I'm not sure.

I've tried to do some kind of proof by contradiction. It runs along the lines: if the element was there, then we must have missed it by eliminating a range that contained that element. The gap between the potential position and the position it's supposed to be must be minimal. In the end if there are two elements and you check the first element, that is either the element, or the element behind the place where the element could have been.

I've also tried to think about reducing the case with the element present, to the case without the element but that approach led nowhere. I feel like I'm hand-waving the proof and grasping at straws.

Is the statement in the question true? If so, could you prove it?

Comment: I can prove it for my own code, but not for yours (even if you had included it). It really depends on how you're tracking the bounds of the search.

Comment: Obvious non-answer: No it doesn't: in c++ `std::binary_search`returns a `bool`, so it's not an index / iterator ;-)

Comment: @stefan but `std::lower_bound` does.

Comment: Binary search is an *algorithm,* not an API. What it returns isn't part of the algorithm description. It is possible to imagine binary search APIs that return void, boolean, negative numbers, anything you like.

Comment: @stefan I had mentioned behavior like lower_bound in C++ or the value returned by Arrays.binarySearch.

Comment: @ejp In general, yes, but you can view it as an API of Java's Array. Here is the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D%2Cbyte%29

Comment: @ssh You asked about 'binary search'. That's an algorithm. You also accepted an answer that starts 'it depends how you implement', which doesn't support your claim that you were asking about a specific API. If you were asking about a specific API you should have said so in the first place, and you should have cited it properly as `Arrays.binarySearch()`. You should also have read its Javadoc, which contains the answer to your question, instead of merely citing it in a belated comment.

Comment: @EJP I was looking for a proof and I got the answer in the comment of the answer I had accepted. The javadoc I cited doesn't contain the proof I was seeking. Binary search algorithm as I'm familiar with, and the implementation of the `Arrays.binarySearch` API both exhibit the same semantics when an element is missing. I was only looking for the proof which I got in the comment of the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you implement binary search.

For example, one way to implement it like you describe is to have it search for the first element that is larger than or equal to your element. Then, when the binary search stops, the position it stops on is the answer (either the actual element, or where it should be inserted).

Example code:

```
binary_search(v: value to search, a: list to search in, n: list size):
    left = 0, right = n

    while left < right:
        m = (left + right) / 2
        if a[m] >= v: // this is the important part:
                      // even if we find it, we continue,
                      // so we find the first such value.
            right = m
        else:
            left = m + 1

    return left
```

Example outputs:

```
binary_search(3, {1, 2, 4}, 3) = 2
binary_search(0, {1, 2, 3}, 3) = 0
binary_search(2, {1, 2, 3}, 3) = 1
```

This should be trivial to adapt to return values in the format you mentioned.

For the implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D%2Cbyte%29), we can prove it like this: if the element is found, its position is obviously returned, so let's focus on the not found case. Eventually, the binary search loop will exit because `low == high + 1`.

Let's see what would have happened if the element was found right before this exit, considering for example `low = high = K`. Then the element would have been found at position `K`. Since it wasn't, we will either set `low = K + 1` or `high = K - 1`.

Since the element wasn't found, returning `low` will return what you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer IVlad, but I'm already aware of how it can be implemented. It's just that I've observed the statement I posted in the question on examples and this is further confirmed by similar API's documentation. I did exactly what you implemented and tested it on examples similar to your own. What I'm trying to understand is how I can prove that this is true.

Comment: @ssh - the proof follows from the construction of the algorithm: `search for the first element that is larger than or equal to your element`. If your element exists, it will return it. If it doesn't, it will return the first larger element, which is where your element should be inserted. Then it's just a matter of implementing the algorithm that does this. The commented lines are what take care of that particular implementation: even if we find an element equal to what we're searching for, we still move to the left interval, to find the **first** such element.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how your proof works for the binary search you've implemented. I was wondering if you could explain how it works for standard binary search (without the = in the >= part) as the  "standard" implementation of binary search: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D%2Cbyte%29

Comment: @ssh - I have tried to sketch a proof for that, let me know if you'd like me to clarify further.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It makes sense to me now.

Comment: your output for `binary_search(4, {1, 2, 3}, 3)` is `2` shouldn't it be `3` .

Comment: @userab I just implemented my pseudocode in Python and the output is `3` for your example. Are you sure your implementation is correct? Here is my Python implementation: https://pastebin.com/fC87x8b3

Comment: mybad, I dry runned multiple times before commenting. Missed that you initialized with `right=n` and not `n-1` which was giving me output as `2`.